# Derivating an integral

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a question about, how can i derivate an expression of the form $$
F\left( u \right) = \int\nolimits_{C_1 }^{C_2 } {f\left( {ux} \right)\mathrm{d}x} 
$$
where $
C_1 ,C_2 
$
are constants.
I have no idea :/

Comment: This is called [differentiating under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign). But since $C_1$ and $C_2$ are constants, the answer is simply $\int_{C_1}^{C_2} \frac{\partial}{\partial u}f(ux) dx$.

Comment: ..., which is $\int_{C_1}^{C_2}xf'(ux)\mathrm dx=\frac1u\left([xf(ux)]_{C_1}^{C_2}-\int_{C_1}^{C_2}f(ux)\mathrm dx\right)$ (where the last step is only valid for $u\neq0$).

Comment: But for example here  $$
\eqalign{
  & f\left( a \right) = \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{Arc\tan \left( {ax} \right) - Arc\tan \left( x \right)}}
{x}dx}   \cr 
  &   \cr 
  & \frac{d}
{{da}}f\left( a \right) = \int\limits_0^\infty  {\frac{{dx}}
{{1 + a^2 x^2 }}}  \cr} 
$$
 He forgets the 1/x in the expression he only considered Arctan(ax) but I think that he should derivate with respect to a $ Arctan (ax) / x $ )=

Comment: @August, The new example is **not** of the form you gave in your question. And the differentiation seems ok. Note that you are (partial) differentiating w.r.t. $a$, not $x$. So the $x$ is a constant. Also differentiating $\arctan (ax)$ w.r.t. $a$ gives a spare $x$, thanks to chain rule. These two $x$'s cancel nicely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This operation is called [differentiating under the integral sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign). In the general case, 
$$
F(u) = \int_{a(u)}^{b(u)} g(u,x) dx,
$$
where the limits are functions of the parameter $u$, we have
$$
F'(u) = f(u, b(u)) b'(u) - f(u, a(u)) a'(u) + \int_{a(u)}^{b(u)} \frac{\partial}{\partial u} g(u,x) dx.
$$
In your case, the limits are constants, and $g(u,x)$ has the special form $f(ux)$. So the first two terms drop out, giving:
$$
F'(u) = \int_{C_1}^{C_2} \frac{\partial}{\partial u} f(ux) dx = \int_{C_1}^{C_2} f'(ux) x dx,
$$
thanks to the chain rule.

In general, one cannot "simplify" such answers any further, but in your case you can. Noting that 
$$
F'(u) = \int_{C_1}^{C_2} \frac{x}{u} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(ux) dx,
$$
and integrating by parts, we get:
$$
F'(u) 
= \left. \frac{x}{u} f(ux) \right|_{C_1}^{C_2} - \int_{C_1}^{C_2} \left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \frac{x}{u} \right) \cdot f(ux) dx 
= \ldots
$$
I will leave it to you to complete the answer. You should be able to express the final integral in terms of $F(u)$ itself.

*Edit: As @joriki notes in a comment, the "simplification" step is valid only if $u \neq 0$.*